# What are ^ followed by a character in linux files

Tags: linux, special-characters

In one of my linux log file, I have very weird chars as below, (`^B`, `^D`, `^G`, `^H`, `^O`, `^R` etc)

```
^MhostIPAddress^R^L10.x.x.x
^N
^HappCategory^R^Bsupplychain
^O
^GappName^R^Deventstream
```

If I `cat` the same log,

```
hostIPAddress
         10.x.x.x

appGroupsupplychain

appNameeventstream
```

**Or are those just terminal thing.** I am sshing Linux machine from macos machine.

On Linux,

```
prayagupd@prayagupd:~# bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.46(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

On Macos,

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's is a fairly common way of displaying control characters.

See, for example, the ["In ASCII" section in the "Control character" article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character#In_ASCII) on Wikipedia.

So `^R` would be what you would get by pressing <kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd> on the keyboard.

As to why they show up in your file, I don't know. Maybe they are just there as delimiters to make parsing the log file easier for some other tool? But that's just me speculating.

Comment: I updated the info as I `cat` the logfile it does not have those Control characters. Its actually a logfile created by a different software (flume - https://flume.apache.org/)

Comment: I am not sure either why would they add special chars in the logfile. (flume is tailing a file and writes the state upto which line did it read, to the above logfile I mentioned.)

Comment: @prayagupd Try with `cat -v`. See the `cat` manual.